# R: in barplot midpoints are not centered w.r.t. bars

Tags: r, vector, plot, bar-chart

I have just noticed something strange using `barplot` in R. Let y be the vector

```
> y
[1] 24924006 15310556 11638412  9542834  8696133
```

Using `barplot` on `y` I arrive at the vector of midpoints

```
bp <- barplot(y)
```

Plotting both bars and midpoints I notice that the bars are not centered .w.r.t. the midpoints...and this is odd; in summary, I use

```
bp <- barplot(y)
points(bp)
```

with

[image]

as outcome. Could you please help me solving this little puzzle? I would just have bars with centered mid-points. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you save the `barplot()` result as an object you get the midpoints for the bars.

```
bp <- barplot(y)
bp
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
```

If you use them now in other plotting functions those midpoints should be as `x` values. In call `plot(bp)` they are used as `y` values and `x` values are sequence numbers `1,2,3,4,5` - so they do not correspond to midpoints.

Providing also `y` values, points are plotted as expected.

```
bp <- barplot(y)
points(bp,c(10,20,30,40,50))
```