# Labelling axis in a plot

Tags: r, plot

How do I label each bar below the x-axis, for example if each bar represents a month, how do I get month one, month two, month three etc below each bar.

```
conditiongood <- c(50,65,60,65,59) 
conditionpoor <- c(61,46,51,46,52)   
condition <- rbind(conditiongood,conditionpoor)   

layout(matrix(1:1,1,1)) 

barplot(as.matrix(condition), 
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        xlab="month",
        ylab="subject count",
        main="Monthly condition",
        ylim=c(0, 140)) 

legend(5.25,140.1,
       c("good","poor"), 
       fill=c("darkblue","red"),
       title="condition")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? 
Which is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634431/r-in-barplot-midpoints-are-not-centered-w-r-t-bars).
There are probably more sophisticated ways to do this.

```
# Barplot
bp<-barplot(as.matrix(condition), 
        col=c("darkblue","red"),
        xlab="month",
        ylab="subject count",
        main="Monthly condition",
        ylim=c(0, 140)) 

# x-axis labels
axis(1, at = bp,
     labels=c("month 1", "month 2", "month 3", "month 4", "month 5"),
     cex.axis=1.2)

# Add legend
legend(5.25,140.1,
       c("good","poor"), 
       fill=c("darkblue","red"),
       title="condition")
```

Which will give:

[image]

You probably want to do something on the position of your legend, and I don't think that specifying the `xlab` is necessary if you're going to label each bar individually. 
I won't comment on the choice of colours :)

Comment: Thanks very much that's exactly it! :)