# How to center bars in R barplot() around ticks

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm still struggling with a similar problem as  [R: in barplot midpoints are not centered w.r.t. bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634431/r-in-barplot-midpoints-are-not-centered-w-r-t-bars) .

I want to make a barplot but with my bars centered at the ticks. However, if I do it the way described below, my bars are shifted to the right with 1.2 instead of 1 points.

I need to have my bars centered to conveniently put labels on the bars, so I wanted to ask you if there is a way to do this.

```r
Part1 <- c(2,4,9,18,20)
Part2 <- c(2,5,1,4,0)
counts <- rbind(Part1, Part2)
colnames(counts) <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

x <- barplot(counts, 
  axes = FALSE,  
  col = c("darkgreen", "red"),
  xlim = c(0, 5*1.50),
  ylim = c(0,60)
)
axis(side = 2, pos = 0) 
axis(side = 1, at = c(0,1,2,3,4,5), tick = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Part1 <- c(2,4,9,18,20)
Part2 <- c(2,5,1,4,0)
counts <- rbind(Part1, Part2)
colnames(counts) <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

x<-barplot(counts, 
  axes = FALSE,  
  space = 0,         
  col = c("darkgreen", "red"),
  xlim = c(0, 5*1.50),
  ylim = c(0,60)
)

#create positions for tick marks, one more than number of bars
ticks <- seq_len(length(counts) + 1)
axis(side = 2, pos = 0)
#adding x-axis with offset positions, with ticks, but without labels
axis(side = 1, at = ticks - 0.5, labels = FALSE)
```